# Sending Long Description Along with Attachment using SMTP in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I am not able to Send email when Description increased more than 3000 characters along with the Attachment. Here is the Sample Code.

```
                $mail->IsSMTP( );                       //send via SMTP
                $mail->Host     = SMTP_HOST;            //SMTP servers
                $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;

                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
                $mail->Host     = SMTP_HOST;            //SMTP servers
                $mail->Port     = 25;
                $mail->Username = USER_NAME;
                $mail->Password = USER_PWD;

                $mail->From     = $from_email;
                $mail->FromName = $from_name;

                $mail->ContentType = "text/html";

                $mail->WordWrap = 180;                   // set word wrap
                $mail->CharSet  = 'UTF-8';
                $mail->IsHTML( true );

                $mail->AddAddress( $to_add, $to_name );
                $mail->Subject = "Tutorial get Answered";

                $HTML = "<p>Your tutorial is ready now,</p>";
                $HTML .= "<p>Question ID: " . $q_id. "</p>";
                $HTML .= "<p>Question : " . $row['description'] . "</p>";
                $HTML .= "<p>Posted on: " . $row['created_on'] . "</p>";
                $HTML .= "<p><a href=base_url().'/" . $row['id'] . "/" . my_text($row['description']) . "'>SHOW TUTORIAL</a></p>";
                $HTML .= "<p><br><br>Thank you.</p>";

                $mail->Body=$HTML;

                $mail->Send();
                $msg="Mail send into your email";
```

It is working fine For small description but if  description increases it shows mail sent but it is not showing in inbox.

Comment: Attach code sample and detailed error description.

Answer (score 0):

Check [CI Email Library Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html) and please use this format:

```
$this->load->library('email');

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com'); 
$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  
$this->email->set_mailtype('html');

$this->email->send();
```

Probably this structure will solve your problem 'cause I'm using this one without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $email = $this->input->post('email');       

$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => '**********@gmail.com',
'smtp_pass' => '********',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset' => 'utf-8',
'wordwrap' => TRUE
);            
        //send email with #temp_pass as a link
       $this->load->library('email', $config);
       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('*********@gmail.com', "Name");
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject("Reset your Password");

        $message = "<p>****************</p>";
        $message. = "<p>****************</p>";
        $this->email->message($message);
        $this->email->send();
```